# Boiling coolant in reservoir car not overheating

Tags: mazda, coolant-reservoir

I own a 2003 Mazda money-pit (protege) we have done ALOT to it. Radiator blew so we replaced radiator, hoses and reservoir.car kept overheating, so we Changed head gasket and thermostat. New plugs and wires and harness. Car is running smooth no overheating no missfire now but the coolant is boiling after driving. Is this normal?

Comment: If the cooing system is not pressurised then yes. Does it actually boil or is it just flowing through vigorously?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you looked at the radiator cap? If the cap won't hold pressure, you'll get some of what you're describing.

Comment: Yes it is boiling in the reservoir pretty good. It calms down after sitting for a minute. We just replaced the entire radiator system I’ll change the cap and see if that makes a difference. Thanks for the advice

Comment: Have you measured the temperature of the coolant?